# ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index, when trying to create a seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to make a jointplot out of some sample data and I keep getting the following error and I do not understand why. It is likely that I am missing something obvious as usual. To me I do not understand why it thinks the values are scalar.

The code to create the plot is below.

```
x_fake = np.random.randn(1, 100)
y_fake = -3*x_fake +  2*np.random.randn(1, 100)
sns.jointplot(x = x_fake, y = y_fake, kind = "reg")
```

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `np.random.randn(1,100)` creates a 2D array (of size `1x100`) while 1D arrays are needed. You could e..g. "squeeze" them (`sns.jointplot(x=x_fake.squeeze(), y=y_fake.squeeze(), kind = "reg")`), or just create them as 1D arrays (`x_fake = np.random.randn(100)`). The cryptic error message comes from pandas. Note that the "standard" way of using Seaborn would be via dataframes (which do have 1D columns).

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x_fake = np.random.randn(1, 100)
y_fake = -3 * x_fake + 2 * np.random.randn(1, 100)
sns.jointplot(x=x_fake.squeeze(), y=y_fake.squeeze(), kind="reg")
```

[image: sns.jointplot needs 1D x and y]